# After I use the lappy() function on a data frame the column name changes,how to prevent that from happening?

Tags: r

[image: original dataframe]

The above data frame has dates in the character format.so I used the following command to convert them into date format(using lubridate)

```
in_time_data_formated <- data.frame(lapply(in_time_data[,-1],function(x)ymd_hms(x)))
```

The command returned a data frame like below, the column names seem to be affected (an X got pre-fixed to all column names).How can I preserve the original column name while executing the lapply() function ?

[image]

Comment: Try `as.data.frame()` rather than `data.frame()`.

Comment: As for why, it’s because there are rules for valid column names, and one is that they can’t start with numbers. You can bypass those rules, but many functions may by default alter the names to make them syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use function `data.frame` argument `check.names`. It defaults to `TRUE` and therefore makes sure the df's names start with a letter. Just set it to `FALSE` and the problem is solved.

First a sample data frame.

```
library(lubridate)

set.seed(8350)    # Make the results reproducible
d1 <- as.POSIXct("2015.01.02", format = "%Y.%m.%d") + cumsum(sample(7200, 4))
d2 <- as.POSIXct("2015.01.05", format = "%Y.%m.%d") + cumsum(sample(7200, 4))
d3 <- as.POSIXct("2015.01.06", format = "%Y.%m.%d") + cumsum(sample(7200, 4))
d4 <- as.POSIXct("2015.01.07", format = "%Y.%m.%d") + cumsum(sample(7200, 4))
in_time_data <- data.frame(EmployeeID = 1:4,
                            `2015.01.02` = d1,
                            `2015.01.05` = d2,
                            `2015.01.06` = d3,
                            `2015.01.07` = d4,
                            check.names = FALSE)
```

Note that this data frame was created with `check.names = FALSE` so those values will not be prefixed with a `X`.

```
in_time_data_formated <- data.frame(lapply(in_time_data[,-1], function(x)ymd_hms(x)),
                                    check.names = FALSE)

in_time_data_formated 
#           2015.01.02          2015.01.05          2015.01.06          2015.01.07
#1 2015-01-02 01:08:22 2015-01-05 00:09:33 2015-01-06 00:12:03 2015-01-07 01:10:56
#2 2015-01-02 02:04:09 2015-01-05 00:41:22 2015-01-06 01:45:02 2015-01-07 02:39:40
#3 2015-01-02 03:58:40 2015-01-05 01:05:15 2015-01-06 02:41:09 2015-01-07 03:03:04
#4 2015-01-02 04:14:42 2015-01-05 02:16:27 2015-01-06 03:09:13 2015-01-07 04:23:57
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1) 

x1 <- rnorm(1000,5,1) 
x2 <- rnorm(1000,3,3) 

y    <- .5*(x1*x2) + rnorm(1000,1,3) 
dat  <- data.frame(x1,x2,y) 

var1 <- c("2015-01-02","2015-01-03") 
colnames(dat) <- var1
```

What you can do is set var1 to hold the column names before you use your lapply. Then rename it after the lapply function is executed.